# Adding a column in a python dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I have [this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gKNo.png) called `unique_customers`.

I also have 2 variables defined; `VIP` and `preferred`

I want to add another column that contains a specific string:

- If the value in `amount_spend >= VIP`, I want to add VIP
- If the value in `amount_spend >= preferred`, I want to add preferred

this is what I did:

```
unique_customers['Customer Status'] = 
    np.where(unique_customers[['amount_spent']] >= VIP,
             'VIP', (unique_customers[['amount_spent']] >= preferred,
                     'preferred', 'other'))
```

This is not working. I am receiving the following error:

> `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using `np.where` with more than one condition. Use `np.select` instead. Also, if the value is greater than both `VIP` and `preferred`, what do u wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, the `numpy.where` takes three arguments: `(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. You are passing a `tuple` with three elements to the third argument, but I think you meant to do:

```
unique_customers['Customer Status'] = 
    np.where(unique_customers[['amount_spent']] >= VIP,
             'VIP', 
             np.where(unique_customers[['amount_spent']] >= preferred,
                     'preferred', 
                     'other'))
```